# download pdf from url best approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using the following code below to download Pdf from a url, i would like to have some idea what would be the best practise, I am  just concern with performance and file size thanks.

```
using( WebClient wc = new WebClient() )
{
  byte[] data = wc.DownloadData("http://localhost:81/File/sample.pdf");

  Response.Clear();
  Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
  Response.AppendHeader( "Content-Disposition" , "attachment;filename=data.pdf" );
  Response.BufferOutput = true;
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
  Response.BinaryWrite(data);
  Response.End();

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901381/downloading-pdf-file-using-webrequests ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are concerned about performance/efficiency/security I'd recommend using the framework's `HttpClient` using it you could do something like this:

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);

    // OR to get the content of the file as you do now
    var data = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

    // do whatever you need to do with your file here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about "performance and file size" (by which I assume you mean time on the wire), you're request for the *.pdf file should contain an `accept-encoding` header, something like this:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

Telling the server that you would prefer the pdf file compressed. Then, in your response, you should

- Ensure that response body is suitably compressed in accordance with your requestor's `accept-encoding` header, and
- Add the correct `content-encoding` header to your response. Something like

  ```
  Content-Encoding: gzip
  ```

If you need tools for compression and decompression, [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) is great. Price is right, too.