# C# - Download PDF from URL and convert it into base64 without saving it on a server

Tags: c#, download, webclient

So basically what I want to do is to download a PDF file inside of a Web API from a URL I get as a parameter from the frontend and directly convert said file into a base64 string without saving the file on a file system.

I have already found `WebClient.Download(URL, File)` but that means, that I have to save the file.

So does anyone know any other solution that could work for me?

Comment: WebClient.DownloadData https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144188(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use below code to download **PDF** from url into **base64** string format.

```
string pdfUrl = "URL_TO_PDF";
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
     var bytes = client.DownloadData(pdfUrl);
     string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}
```

Comment: best answer but maybe you can add a using:            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()){

Answer (score 0):

as said in first answer of [Downloading pdf file using WebRequests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901381/downloading-pdf-file-using-webrequests)

```
var fileName = "output/" + date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".pdf";
using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
 resp.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(stream);
```

(resp is

```
 HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

)

then convert to base64

```
 String file = Convert.ToBase64String(stream);
```